# Getting random line from textfile on keypress [C#]

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to get a random line from a text file every time I press F9.

What I'm using is:

```
static class Randomyze
{
    public static string[] allLinks = File.ReadAllLines(@"links.txt");
    public static Random randomLink = new Random();
    public static int setLink = randomLink.Next(0, allLinks.Length - 1);
    public static String getLink = allLinks[setLink];
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F9)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(Randomyze.getLink); 
    }
        return true;
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the same line when I press F9.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setLink` never changes after its initialized

Comment: @SelmanGenç if I want to use setLink as a global var (to use it in other methods and such). What can I do? because IF i make it non-static I cant access it.

Comment: maybe you should not be using a static class then ?

Comment: @RexSixx why you want set link to be a global variable? For why you have here, a local variable makes more sense. Is this variable used somewhere else other than the key press method?

Comment: I also suggest that you learn more about classes and object oriented programming. Specifically, you need to learn how to create instances of a class and use those objects.

Comment: You could define `setLink` as a property so that the value would change every time you get it: `public static int setLink  { get{return randomLink.Next(0, allLinks.Length - 1);}}`

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates one random number when your program starts. You need to modify it so that you generate a new random number each time the key is pressed.

Hint: Do not use `static` at all.

Comment: @ CodeApprentice how I can make it non-static while still being able to use it inside the keypress method (ProcessCmdKey)

Comment: @RexSixx since you need to generate a new number for each key press, a local variable in the method makes more sense than a static variable

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
        public static int setLink = randomLink.Next(0, allLinks.Length - 1);
        public static String getLink = allLinks[setLink];
```

Execute only once when the class is initialized.

Your naming convention is actually pointing you to the way you want to go. Things with verbs (get, set, here) should usually correspond to functions. Try rewriting these as functions, returning items of interest (a link index, a link from the file).

Comment: @ matt_t_gregg Okay thanks.. if I want to use setLink as a global var (to use it in other methods and such). What can I do? because IF i make it non-static I cant access it

Comment: @RexSixx what happens when you make the variable non-static? What error do you get?

Comment: The static nature does confuse things, but isn't a problem in itself.

Comment: @RexSixx You might be confusing the purpose of static in C#. Note that for non-static classes in C# you need to create an instance of the class (with 'new') in order to call its methods.